# Web Scraper Formatting in Python

Tags: python, excel, beautifulsoup, xlsxwriter

So I am scraping a webpage to gather some information and then want the information to be put in an excel sheet. I have this part completed. The part I am struggling with is writing the header in column A that is related to all the data in column B. So I want to print the header next to where the new data starts. Here is the html:

```
<div class="result">
<span class="number"><a href="####">####
  <span class="d" id="number">
  </span>
</span></a> 
<div class="rm">
<span class="detail"><span class="cloud" title="system"></span> information</span>
<span class="detail"><span class="marker" title="location"></span> information</span>
  <br/>
<span class="detail"><span class="cog" title="public"></span> information</span>
  <br/>
<span class="detail"><span class="lock" title="name"></span> information</span>
    <br/>
</div>
  <span class="default">word</span>
```

So my problem occurs when there are multiple classes named "rm". There are two solutions I can think of but can't seem to get the code. Essentially I want system, location, public, and name each in column B and then the number in column A. Then, once the next "rm" div comes, I want the number to be in the cell next to the new information. I can either count how many "detail" spans there are for each rm div or I can print the whole class "result". The only problem with printing the entire class "result" is that all the information goes into one cell, and I need it separated out. Any help is appreciated!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


i = br.open(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(i)
div = soup.findAll('span', attrs={"class":"detail"})
idiv = soup.findAll('span', attrs={"class":"number"})
for val in idiv:
    worksheet.write(counter,0,val.text)
    counter += 1
for val2 in div:
    worksheet.write(row,1,val2.text)
    row += 1
```

So the result of this code is just where the numbers are listed in column A one by one and the information is in by, just as I want it. The problem is I want the number to be next to where the information starts.

Comment: I've tried a lot of different ways. But I'll edit my post and add one of the versions I have.

Comment: What are you trying to associate?

Comment: The number in span class "number" to all of the information in each span class "detail". The problem is that sometimes there are 5 items in the "detail" class, so I need to have some type of counter.